# Transforming string of data into an object in c#

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to solve this issue, which shouldn't be too hard, but I'm stuck on it for far too long now.

This is the data I'm working with `var data = "2,6;2,7;4,14;5,20";` 
It's a string that shows `<modifierGroup>,<modifier>;<modifierGroup>,<modifier>;...`

This is the model I eventually want to get my data in:

```
public class ModifierGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Modifier> Modifiers { get; set; }
}

public class Modifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Right now I keep thinking I need to get my data in this format, so I can eventually push it into the model:

```
Key=2
    Value=6
    Value=7
    
Key=4
    Value=14
    
Key=5
    Value=20
```

But I could be wrong. I'd love to keep the code short. So I'd rather prevent loops in loops and doing if statements over and over. Best case scenario I get a 1 or 2-liner of code, but if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.

Comment: Create a dictionary<int, List<int>>. Split the string by `;` that will give you array of string. Use ForEach Linq to process each item in the array. Each item in the array can be further split by `,`.  Add the item in the dictionary with the first part of the string is key (modifiergroup) and nextone is value(modifier).

Comment: Try this regular expression: `var matches = Regex.Matches(data, @"(?<=(^|;))(?<key>\d+),(?<value>\d+)(;|$)").Select(m => new { key = m.Groups["key"].Value, value = m.Groups["value"].Value })`

Comment: Do you have to use that string format, or can you change it to something more structured? If you can represent the data as JSON, this all becomes very easy. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just use `Split` and `GroupBy` with a projection

```
var data = "2,6;2,7;4,14;5,20";
var result = data
  .Split(";")
  .Select(x => x.Split(",")
     .Select(int.Parse)
     .ToArray())
  .GroupBy(x => x[0])
  .Select(x => new ModifierGroup()
  {
     Id = x.Key, 
     Modifiers = x.Select(y => new Modifier() {Id = y[1]}).ToList()
  });
```